# Select child element of sibling node (without leaving current node) in XLST

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML that looks like this:

```
<library>
    <album>
        <!-- Album title, length, # of tracks, etc -->
        <playas>
            <extension>.mp3</extension>
            <type>audio/mpeg</type>
        </playas>
        <playas>
            <extension>.ogg</extension>
            <type>audio/ogg</type>
        </playas>

        <track>
            <!-- Track number, title, length -->
        </track>
        <!-- Many, many more tracks -->
    </album>
</library>
```

And in my XLS file, I want to use `xls:for-each` to determine each track's `source` src attribute. Here's what doesn't work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="track">
    <audio>
        <!-- Parent (album)'s playas elements -->
        <xsl:for-each select="../playas">
            <source>
                <xsl:attribute name="src">
                    <!-- Parent (album)'s title + '-src', where I store the audio files
                         along with current node (playas)'s extension -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="../title" />-src/<xsl:value-of select="title" /><xsl:value-of select="extension" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="type">
                    <xsl:value-of select="srctype" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </source>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </audio>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The code above gives `<source src="AlbumTitle-src/.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> (or .ogg and audio/ogg)` - the current `track`'s title isn't present. However, the code is created correctly for each track, so all I need to know is how to get the current track's title (from the context of playas).

I've also tried `for-each select="preceding-sibling::playas"`, with no luck. How can I access the children of each `playas` without "leaving" the current `track`?

**Edit:** I know this would be very easily done by simply hard-coding a `<source>` for each playas extension, but I want to do it with minimal implementation.

**Edit 2:** @Peter: my expected output for each track (in equivalent HTML) is

```
<audio>
    <source src="AlbumTitle-src/track.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="AlbumTitle-src/track.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

Comment: By which sub-element are you thinking of correlating each track with each playas? Will each track always have all playas formats for that album available?

Comment: Yes, I've made it so that each track will be available with each playas extension. I'm not sure what your first question is asking, but I need to access the "current" track's title from within each playas.

Comment: @trojansdestroy: can you please show us your expected output. you can't make single attributes <extension> and <type> and process two <playas> elements, I mean you can't write multiple values into single attributes. Thank yolu, Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are inside of `<xsl:for-each select="../playas">` you already are in the `playas` element context. So to retrieve its `title` child, all you need is `<xsl:value-of select="title" />`. And to retrieve the track title you coud set a variable when inside of the `track` for-each and use it in the source output element, such as:

```
<xsl:for-each select="track">
<audio>
    <xsl:variable name="track_title" select="title" />
    <!-- Parent (album)'s playas elements -->
    <xsl:for-each select="../playas">
        <source>
            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                <!-- Parent (album)'s title + '-src', where I store the audio files
                     along with current node (playas)'s extension -->
                <xsl:value-of select="title" />-src/<xsl:value-of select="$track_title" /><xsl:value-of select="extension" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="type">
                <xsl:value-of select="srctype" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </source>
    </xsl:for-each>
</audio>
```

Comment: The playas element doesn't have a title element (I only need the track title). Using a variable does work, so thank you! I didn't know variables were an option. Is there a way to do it otherwise though? It just seems like variables are a kind of "hack" and there should be a direct way to access the track title.